# Visual Studio Replacement for C#?

Tags: software-recommendation, ide, compiler, c#

Currently studying a Computer Science Degree, in Programming we are using C# in Visual Studio. So need a replacement that can run work already started in Visual.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin, a developer for Mono, created MonoDevelop, which is an IDE for C# on Ubuntu.
As far as I know, it can open VS projects. You can find it within the Synaptic Package Manager or Ubuntu Software Center. [Here](http://www.monodevelop.com/) is the homepage. Any other questions about it can most likely be answered by their [FAQ](http://www.monodevelop.com/help/faq/).

Answer (score 1):

For Linux and Mac, **Visual Studio Code(VS Code)** is the best alternative of **Visual Studio**. It is great code editor for Node.js and C# developers. You can also use it for other languages too. Also Visual Studio Code is an open source software. Its [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) is on GitHub.

[Download the latest .deb package of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

Another alternative is [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), which is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. Mono is sponsored by **Microsoft**. [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) is the official IDE of **Mono**. You can also use **MonoDevelop** for F# and other languages too.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Mono project http://monodevelop.com/

Or Visual Studio https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

And for more:

- Check: [Mono>development-environments](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/development-environments)
- Online compiler: https://repl.it/languages/csharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Code,  It's a lightweight code editor, and could be used for C# and so many other languages by adding relevant plugins.